# When new email arrives (V3) Office365 Polling Frequency

Tags: azure-logic-apps, office365connectors

In Azure Logic Apps (Standard), I am creating a workflow that gets triggered when a new email arrives to a mailbox. However, I see there is a delay of 20-30 sec after the mail arrives to the mailbox. I see in "When a new email arrives(V3)", there is no way to specify the polling frequency. How to pull the email immediately upon arrival?

PS: I am saying it take more than 20s by checking the difference between workflowContext.trigger.outputs.body.receivedDataTime and the current datetime when workflow runs.

Comment: You can’t, you used to be able to control it but you can’t anymore. You gotta live with it. Otherwise, you’d need to orchestrate your own connector.

Comment: Yes as mentioned by Skin, you can't control now.
Can you try with trigger of type "When a new email arrives in a shared mailbox (V2)" and see if delay is reduced or not?

Answer (score 0):

```
How to pull the email immediately upon arrival?
```

- As mentioned by @skin the simple answer for your query is **NO**.

  ```
   However, I see there is a delay of 20-30 sec after the mail arrives to the mailbox. I see in "When a new email arrives(V3)", there is no way to specify the polling frequency.
  ```
- Yes, your right there is no way to mention polling frequency in When a new email arrives(v3).
- But if you are ok with the alternative trigger **When a new email arrives in a shared mailbox (V2)** you can try this trigger and check any time variation is helpful in your case.
  This trigger is used to pull the email immediately upon arrival.
- Refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/720614/when-a-new-email-arrives-in-a-shared-mailbox-%28v2%29) for more information related to When a new email arrives in a shared mailbox (V2) trigger.
- The delay of 20-30 seconds after an email arrives to a mail box is caused by the trigger limitation for shared mailboxes and cannot be reduced.

  Reference MS [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365/).

.

Comment: Thank you, What is the "SharedMailBox" address? Is that different from the account that i used to create office365 connection? Or should i just specify the same email address i used for creating the office365 connection? Also want to know if the polling interval is defaulted within the V3 connector?

Comment: There is no way to specify the polling frequency in "When a new email arrives(V3).The shared mailbox address is the email address that is used to send and receive emails from a group of people. To create a shared mailbox, log in as an administrator and click Groups > Shared mailboxes. To add a shared mailbox on Office 365, open Outlook on the web and go to the shared mailbox, open a message sent to the shared address, click Reply, and at the bottom of the message click Add cc or Add bcc